# Errors in compete table foreign key

Tags: mysql, mariadb, foreign-keys, schema

I keep getting an error about my foreign key in the table 'compete'. I have been trying to look up what is wrong, but none of the examples seem to be my issue. Can anyone help me out? This is the error I keep getting:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `database`.`compete` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE athlete (
        athlete_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        country TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
        name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
        birthdate DATE NOT NULL,
        age INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        height_inch INT UNSIGNED,
        weight_lbs INT UNSIGNED,
        PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE sport (
        sport_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        sport TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (sport_id)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE olympics (
        olympics_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        season TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
        year YEAR NOT NULL,
        city TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (olympics_id)
    );  
    
    CREATE TABLE sport_events (
        sport_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        event_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        event TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (sport_id, event_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (sport_id) REFERENCES sport (sport_id)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE athlete_sport (
        athlete_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        sport_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (athlete_id) REFERENCES athlete (athlete_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (sport_id) REFERENCES sport (sport_id)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE compete (
        athlete_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        olympics_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        event_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        medal TINYTEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (athlete_id) REFERENCES athlete (athlete_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (olympics_id) REFERENCES olympics (olympics_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES sport_events (event_id)   
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop and recreate the `sport_events` table, and use the `event_id` column as the first column of its primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE sport_events (
    sport_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    event_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    event TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id,sport_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (sport_id) REFERENCES sport (sport_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `sport_events` table you have declared primary key with two columns.
`PRIMARY KEY (sport_id, event_id)`

But in `compete` table you have added `FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES sport_events (event_id)` with a single column.

That's why you get
`errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"` error.

Drop the `complete` table first and then `sport_events` table after that. Then change the primary key `PRIMARY KEY (event_id)` in `sport_events` table.

Or, simply switch `PRIMARY KEY (event_id, sport_id)`. This will work.

After that create both tables.